# Recursive query does not return records when Parent Product and Child Product have the same code

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a table that maps the production line.
The fields are:
Product: Output product of the machine.
ParentProduct: Input product in the machine.
Machine: Machine processing product.
I am using commom table expressions (CTE's) to get the data recursively.
This works when the names of incoming and outgoing products are different.

```
use DB_TEST

DECLARE @TableTest TABLE ( 
    Product nvarchar(10) null,
    ParentProduct  nvarchar(10) null,
    Machine nvarchar(10) null
)

begin

    insert into @TableTest values ('Product1', null, 'MACH1' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product2', null, 'MACH2'  );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product3', null, 'MACH3'  );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product4', 'Product1', 'MACH1' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product5', 'Product1', 'MACH1' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product6', 'Product2', 'MACH2' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product7', 'Product4', 'MACH2' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product8', 'Product4', 'MACH3' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product9', 'Product5', 'MACH1' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product10', 'Product6', 'MACH2' );
    insert into @TableTest values ('Product11', 'Product8', 'MACH3' );

;WITH tree AS
(
    SELECT P.Machine, p.Product, p.ParentProduct, [level] = 1, [path] = cast(p.Product as varchar(100))
    FROM @TableTest p
    WHERE p.ParentProduct IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT P2.Machine, p2.Product, p2.ParentProduct,  [level] = tree.[level] + 1, 
           [path] = Cast(tree.[path] + ' > ' + cast(p2.Product as varchar(10)) as varchar(100))
    FROM @TableTest p2 INNER JOIN tree ON tree.Product = p2.ParentProduct 
)
SELECT * FROM tree 
Order by machine
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

end;
```

Result OK.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

But when the names are the same (ParentProduct = Product) the product does not appear in the result.
In this example 'Product8' has the same name as your source product.

```
insert into @TableTest values ('Product1', null, 'MACH1' );
insert into @TableTest values ('Product2', null, 'MACH2'  );
insert into @TableTest values ('Product3', null, 'MACH3'  );
insert into @TableTest values ('Product4', 'Product1', 'MACH1' );
insert into @TableTest values ('Product5', 'Product1', 'MACH1' );
insert into @TableTest values ('Product6', 'Product2', 'MACH2' );
insert into @TableTest values ('Product7', 'Product4', 'MACH2' );

/* ---- HERE, THE INPUT PRODUCT HAS THE SAME OUTPUT PRODUCT NAME. -----*/
insert into @TableTest values ('Product8', 'Product8', 'MACH3' );

insert into @TableTest values ('Product9', 'Product5', 'MACH1' );
insert into @TableTest values ('Product10', 'Product6', 'MACH2' );
insert into @TableTest values ('Product11', 'Product8', 'MACH3' );
```

And the result is NOT OK. Product8 does not appear in the result

[image: a descrição da imagem aqui]

**I need to display this path for 'product8':

Product1 > Product4 > Product8 > Product8 > Product11


This product needs to appear twice on the path.

How can I recursively solve this problem?**

Comment: The root case of the CTE looks for rows where the parent product is null.  The recursive case then joins on that.  However, for product 8, there is no matching root case, so there are no rows produced for that one

Comment: Yes to get the results you say you want, you would need a line where Product8 is the child of Product4, for starters